# Color data for for each degenerate triangle

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, metal

I want to specify a color for each strip in my triangle strip separated by degenerate triangles. As of now, I am sending that data with each vertex so my vertices consists of: `[ PosX, PosY, PosZ, ColorX, ColorY, ColorZ, ColorW ]`. However, the color data is constant for every vertex until it may change after a degenerate triangle, and therefore I am wasting 8 bytes per vertex (Wide P3 colors).

Obviously using many draw calls instead of degenerate triangles would solve the memory issue (by using an uniform buffer to store the color for each draw call), but would also create a massive performance overhead which is unwanted.

Since I only have simple shapes, the degenerate triangles are better than index buffers in my case. Although the current implementation of repeating the color data for all vertices in each strip works, I would like to know if there is another way to pass this data more efficiently to the GPU. Could not find much about this topic on Google (presumably because degenerate triangles are not very common nowadays). If anyone could give me some insight on how the memory usage may be optimised without worsening the performance (maybe by using another buffer? I imagine I need to be able to tell which strip separated by degenerate triangles I am currently drawing in the shader) it would be highly appreciated.

I am using Swift 4 and Metal.

Comment: 16 bytes per vertex just for colour information? As in float per component? Does it have to be that precise?